# how to change width of scrollbar-track (line under ScrollBar)

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I want to code scrollbar like this design:

[image]

it means width of `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` must `5px` and width of `-webkit-scrollbar-track` must `2px` but i can't change width of `-webkit-scrollbar-track` independent of `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`.

```css
.main {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid red;
overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Scrollbar */

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #dddddd;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #dddddd;*/
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #9e9e9e;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did you check which browser support `-webkit-scrollbar-track`?? For example, Firefox doesn't support it

Comment: hello, yes i checked in chrome and its ok. but just width of `-webkit-scrollbar-track` doesn't change.

Comment: In your css you forgot to set `width: 2px;` for `-webkit-scrollbar-truck`

Comment: i set but not change anything. do you test?

Comment: I can't check it right now, because I'm using Firefox and I'm on Ubuntu, sorry. But I will try something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for making scrollbar-track width thinner you can use `border-left` and `border-right` in `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` with `transparency` and also change `background` to transparent and use `box-shadow` to change the color of track

```css
.main {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid red;
overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Scrollbar */

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-left: 1.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1.5px solid transparent;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #9e9e9e;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
 <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add 'border-left' and 'border-right' to both track and thumb..

check this:

```
.main {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  max-height: 250px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Scrollbar */

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #dddddd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-left: 9px solid white;
  border-right: 9px solid white;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #9e9e9e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid white;
  border-right: 5px solid white;
}
```